# JavaScript Sign In with twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

Im looking for a javascript api for twitter login for websites, and i can find only server side api.
Am I looking somewhere wrong or is there not a javascript api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no JS api, you need to use oAuth,

You can use this library, its pretty cool
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: Yea but thats PHP and it will be problematic for my system. thx anyway i guess.

Comment: But Problem with using javascript is that anyone who views your page can also view your consumer key and secret which must be kept private.

Now, someone could write an app that uses your app credentials and do naughty and bad things to the point that twitter and users ban you, and there isnt anything you can do.

Twitter do state that every possible effort must be made to keep these values private to avoid this happening

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to use oAuth in Browser based JavaScript securely.

Comment: Well facebook does use a refferer insurence that allows you to only access the app through the api with a specific domain name that you stated in advance.